# Cantidad de mensajes por segundo PubNub

Tags: java

Alguien sabe cuantos mensajes por segundo un mismo publicador (publish)  puede enviar a varios suscriptores (subscribe).
Por ejemplo el publicador puede enviar 100 mensajes por segundo y son enviados rapidamente.
Por ejemplo el publicador puede enviar 10000 mensajes por segundo y pubnub los entrega a los suscriptores sin aplicar ningún delay.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta de Stackoverflow en inglés va a resolver tus dudas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416918/throttle-pubnub-publish-message

Comment: Muchas gracias fue de gran ayuda.

Comment: De nada! Siento no poder darte una respuesta yo mismo, ya que nunca he utilizado ese servicio.